# Android unicode u23F8 (pause symbol) color

Tags: android, button, unicode, textcolor, pause

I can't change color of the [u23F8 (pause symbol)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23f8/index.htm).
play symbol looks ok and I can change its color

```
playPauseButton = new Button(mContext);
playPauseButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 72);
playPauseButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

...

if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    playPauseButton.setText("\u23F8");
} else {
    playPauseButton.setText("\u25B6")
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The TextView font renders \u23F8 and \u25B6 as an emoji, which means it basically uses a predefined image, so font colors are ignored on these.